# Traversing to a parent in Ractivejs mustache

Tags: javascript, mustache, ractivejs

I'm trying to get an object above a loop so I can grab it for a function but I get undefined when trying to do `../../this` which I thought you could do after looking at the [docs](http://docs.ractivejs.org/latest/references).

My code currently looks like this:

```
{{#each locations}}
    <input type="text" name="location[]" value="{{location}}">
    <ul>
        {{#each typeaheadValue}}
            <li on-click="selectValue:{{../../this}}">{{value}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
{{/each}}
```

Each location object contains an ID and other properties which I would like to access in the selectValue function but I'm getting undefined when trying to find the current parent object.

Would I have to instead get the index of the parent each and pass that to the function to get which location object I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use `this` at the end of a restricted reference. You can use the index and collection to get a reference to the current iteration item directly in the template:

```js
new Ractive({
  el: document.body,
  template: '#template',
  data: {
    locations: [ "Portland", "Brooklyn", "Paris"],
    typeaheadValue: [ "one", "two", "three" ]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="http://cdn.ractivejs.org/edge/ractive.js"></script>

<script id='template' type='text/html'>
{{#each locations:l}}
    <input type="text" name="location[]" value="{{.}}">
    <ul>
        {{#each typeaheadValue}}
            <li on-click="selectValue:{{locations[l]}}">{{.}} - {{locations[l]}}</li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
{{/each}}

</script>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why `this` isn't allowed?

Comment: semantically speaking `this` applies to the current context and all subsequent reference restrictions are applied to the context of `this`. That being said, it could be added :)